# getting BadMethodCallException in laravel

Tags: laravel-4

```html
class Degree extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'degrees';
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_degree');
    }
    
    public function university()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('University');
    }
    
    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('DegreeType', 'degree_type_id');
    }
   


///////another model is//////

class DegreeType extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'degree_types';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'approved'];
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_degree');
    }
}


//////and finally controller is ///////

foreach ($degreeTypeC as $param)
        {
            $u = $u->whereHas('degree', function($q) use($param){
                $q->whereHas('type', function($q) use($param){
                    $q->where('id', '=', $param);
                });
            });
        }
```

Giving error:

> {"error":{"type":"BadMethodCallException","message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::degree()","file":"/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php","line":2113}}

Where is the problem?

Comment: What are the columns in your 'degrees' table?

Comment: Is there a degree method on your User model?

Comment: Hello JMc in degrees table columns: {`id`,`university_id`,`degree_type_id`,`degree_subject_id`,`degree_result_id`,`degree_year`,`name`}

Comment: No there is no degree method in user model. Is it necessary???

Comment: Thank You, Matt Burrow It's working